Slayer exciter as driver circuit for Tesla Coil
I have problem understanding voltage divider on push/pull bases, yellow box on schematics . (push-pull concept is ok to me). Because, if i understand correctly (which is questionable), if i have 20V input, on base of 2N3904 i than have 13V (in datasheet max B-E voltage is 5V??), similar on base of 2N3906 i have 7V (but  max B-E is 5V).
Second, if 2N3904 is on, from schematics on base i have 24V but Vgs=20V MAX..??
This schematic i took from Hyperspace pirate video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xImmwL5MR0o&t=314s) and corrected it but it is not good enough i already burn 6 MOSFETS and i desperately need some suggestions to improve circuit not to burn then further more..
Thanks in advance

It is possible, that you have to swap the primary coil polarity. Only one polarity provides the correct feedback phase. If this is wrong, the FETs just conduct and burn.

You should "surely" limit your supply voltage to something like 15-17 V. You can obtain then something like 20 kV at output "breakout".

When your circuit starts consider the VGS .Look at the fet specs which will cause a huge current to flow .Remember that the osc starts in Analog class A .Your huge currents will actually reduce mosfet transconductance because they are pretty much bottomed out .The system gain at this point can get below unity so it wont start and will promptly burn out .For the osc to run the average system gain must be greater than unity .So consider less bias at startup so there is some  gain .Consider current limit on the input .Also consider moving the bias from start to run ,for example it could run on 2V and start on 5V .I have done lots of ZVS royer and always prebucked the input to effect control and limit current to stop start up burn .I think the slayer has similiar issues but will be easier to tame .
